# Passing Data from skills bot to root bot without using dialogs

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I have 2 skills connected to a RootBot, and I am trying to invoke Skill B from Skill A (at the end of Skill A, and with no further action by the user). I know that I have to go through the RootBot for that. I have a problems to handle:

Passing data from Skill A -> RootBot

if i can pass data from skill A to Rootbot i can
Pass data from RootBot-> Skill B

I'm using below snippet to call skill from root bot

```
var response = await _skillClient.PostActivityAsync(_botId, targetSkill, _skillsConfig.SkillHostEndpoint, turnContext.Activity, cancellationToken);
```

I'm using below snippet to end conversation in skill bot

```
var endOfConversation = Activity.CreateEndOfConversationActivity();
endOfConversation.Code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully;
```

is it possible to pass data from skills to bot without using dialogs